# If $p$ is an odd prime with $p ≡ 3(\mod 4)$, then $(p-1)! + p\mathbb{Z} = (-1)^{(p-1)/2} +p\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove if true. Give counterexample if false.
If $p$ is an odd prime with $p ≡ 3(\mod 4)$, then $$(p-1)! + p\mathbb{Z} = (-1)^{(p-1)/2} +p\mathbb{Z}.$$

Proof. $p ≡ 3(\mod 4)$ implies $4|p-3$.
Wilson's Theorem says: If p is prime, then $$(p-1)! + p\mathbb{Z} = -1 + p\mathbb{Z}$$
or equivalently $$(p-1)! ≡ -1(\mod p).$$
The latter implies $$p|(p-1)!+1.$$

I'm not sure where to go from there, or if that is even that correct approach to begin with.

Comment: You have $p=4k+3$ hence $(p-1)/2 \equiv 1 \mod 2$

Answer (score 1):

From Wilson's Theorem, we know that $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$,

Hence, it suffices to prove that $$(-1)^{\frac{p-1}2}=-1$$

which is equivalent to proving that $\frac{p-1}2$ is an odd number

If $p = 4k+3$, then $$\frac{p-1}{2}=\frac{4k+2}{2}=2k+1$$ which is an odd number.